# Laravel: LDAP-Auth invalid DN syntax

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, ldap, openldap

I am using Laravel `4.0.10` and [ccovey/ldap-auth](https://github.com/ccovey/ldap-auth) for user authentication. On the server end I have `OpenLDAP` server created with [Turnkey OpenLDAP](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/openldap). I've followed the instructions but I'm getting an error when trying to connect to server.

**Error:**

```
Bind to Active Directory failed. Check the login credentials and/or server details. AD said: Invalid DN syntax
```

My `app/config/adldap.php` file:

```
<?php

return array(
    'account_suffix' => '@mreza.vpl',

    'domain_controllers' => array("ldap.vpl.lan"), // An array of domains may be provided for load balancing.

    'base_dn' => 'DC=mreza,DC=vpl',

    'admin_username' => 'admin',

    'admin_password' => 'mypassword',
    'real_primary_group' => true, // Returns the primary group (an educated guess).

    'use_ssl' => false, // If TLS is true this MUST be false.

    'use_tls' => false, // If SSL is true this MUST be false.

    'recursive_groups' => true,
);
```

I added this line to `app/config/auth.php`:

```
'username' => 'uid'
```

My OpenLDAP database looks like this:
[image]
I want to authenticate against `People` group

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? I've been trying to set this up for a few days now. I am new to `LDAP` though.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change the Admin username to either `cn=Admin` or `cn=admin,DC=mreza,DC=vpl` and try to connect.  You need a full DN to bind, generally.